# How to add spacific phone numbers in database to multilevel list view in android

Tags: android

I am new in Android Technology. I am developing SMS Spam Filtering project in android. I want to create a view like below image. So, please help me for implementing this view.

[image]

I try to implement above list view for showing sender numbers. I implement little bit code , this shows only one sender number. I does not add another new number in list view. This code I send you

```
package com.smsfilter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by DELL on 10-02-2016.
*/
public class Move extends Activity {
    ListView lv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_move);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmove);

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(0);
        final List<Message> sms;
        DB_Message dbmessage = new DB_Message(this);
        // dbmessage.deleteAll();

        sms = dbmessage.ViewMessageData(0);
        for (int i=0;i<1;i++) {
            al.add(sms.get(i).getmAddress());
            // al.add(sms.get(i).getmAddress());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,al);
        sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv1.setAdapter(sadapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // lv1.getSelectedItemId();
                // sms.get(0).getmAddress();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID " +sms.get(0).getmAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent customlistintent = new Intent(Move.this, SpamActivity.class);
                startActivity(customlistintent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am fetching sender number in Sqlite Database. This code is given below,

```
DB_Message dbmessage = new DB_Message(this);
sms = dbmessage.ViewMessageData(0);
for (int i=0;i<1;i++) {
    al.add(sms.get(i).getmAddress());
    // al.add(sms.get(i).getmAddress());
}
```

Please help me for fetching new sender number from database and this add in list view. Please give a solution.

Comment: I want to add a specific phone number from database to list view, like phone inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Hemant,
If I am understanding your question correctly, it requires a whole lot of work with tutorials because:

For Sqlite Database Implementation, you need to extend a OpenSqliteHelper as shown in [Sqlite Tutorial For Android by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

For the ListView to look like what you want to, you may want to implement a customer list view as shown in [ListView tutorial by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

If you need a reference to a project that uses both, including converting the List returned by the Database to a Custom ArrayAdapter, you can use my project as a reference which uses a database to store things to do and then displays them on a custom list view at [To Do App by Khanal](https://github.com/khanal-abhi/todos)

It is too in depth to go through the code line by line but as you make a progress, feel free to ask questions based on where you are stuck and we can probably help you with it.

ps. If you want to get the sender info from the contacts in the android as well as intercepting the sms, you will need the permission to be set as well and may not have to use a custom database.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestion.

Comment: I created database and custom list view. I do not know  how to add specific number in list view from database.